# Hold[Expression] (or similar) in InputField that truly holds the input unmodified

Tags: hold, inputfield

I am trying to design a user interface where the specific form that the user enters in InputFields are left unchanged. For example, if the user puts in a number in scientific notation, it would be really nice for that value in the field to stay the same, even though it is modified internally into a different form. None of the Hold-type functions seem to do what I want (and only Hold[Expression] seems to be an option in InputField anyway).

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `InputField[Dynamic[var], Boxes]`? .. combined with `Dynamic[ToExpression@x]` to use the evaluated values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
InputField[Dynamic[var], Boxes]
```

[image]

```
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[var], Boxes], 
  Dynamic[var], 
  Dynamic[RawBoxes @ var], 
  Dynamic[ToExpression @ var] }]
```

[image]