# InputField with Boxes-held formatting fails inside Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, hold, inputfield

This is an outgrowth of an [earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202754/holdexpression-or-similar-in-inputfield-that-truly-holds-the-input-unmodifie).

I have an extensive user interface that has InputFields that I want to hold their specific structure as input by the user (*e.g.*, keeping scientific notation if they enter the numbers that way). And since the code will be pretty much the same throughout for each of these (many) InputFields, I want a function to do it for me. I have what seems to be a great way to do this:

```
SetAttributes[HoldInputField, HoldFirst];
HoldInputField[var_, OptionsPattern[FieldSize -> 10]] := 
  DynamicModule[{boxes = ToBoxes[var]}, 
    InputField[Dynamic[boxes, 
      Function[result, boxes = result; var = ToExpression[boxes]]], 
      Boxes, FieldSize -> OptionValue[FieldSize]]]
```

We can test it like this:

```
test = 3;
Row[{HoldInputField[test], " = ", Dynamic[test]}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, if the Row statement is itself within a Dynamic wrapper, the behavior fails:

[image]

Why do I need to do this? Because the number of fields itself is dynamic. For example:

```
numFields = 3;
fieldvalue[index_] = 0;
Column[{Row[{"Number of fields: ",SetterBar[Dynamic[numFields],Range[5]]}], 
        Panel[Dynamic[Column[
          Row[{"Field ", #, ": ", HoldInputField[fieldvalue[#]], 
              " = ", fieldvalue[#]}] & /@ Range[numFields]]]]}]
```

[image]

Are there any ways to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you need to keep information about typesetting you should not do `ToExpression` until you really need to. Otherwise you lose it and next time the field is called with a fraction value that contains no information about formatting. Shortly, your input fields should be a controller for a an array of boxes. You can use them however you need later.

Comment: try `MakeBoxes[var]` in place of `ToBoxes[var]`?

Comment: @kglr: Doesn't seem to work. The early examples start with the variable name in the input field rather than the initial value. And the multi-field example has the value continually reverting to the variable names.

Comment: @Kuba: That's hard to envision for this application, because I am using those values to update graphs in real-time.

Comment: I think I see the issue. When numFields updates, MMA reexecutes Column in its entirety, which means that it destroys and recreates the HoldInputField instantiations, which reinitializes the boxes variables. So I need to either create the fields once at the beginning and then only have the Dynamic functionality change the DISPLAY of these pre-existing fields (and I didn't want to have a fixed max, so maybe create on the fly but check for existence before recreating?), or I need to store the boxes information and pass it to the function. The last option seems the easiest to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have a workaround, based on my comment above. I maintain the value of the boxes variable between instantiations. I wish there were a more elegant solution, and will be happy to entertain such if anyone has any ideas. Regardless, here is the test code that works for me:

```
SetAttributes[HoldInputField, HoldAll];
  HoldInputField[var_, boxes_, OptionsPattern[FieldSize -> 10]] := 
   DynamicModule[{}, If[boxes == Null, boxes = ToBoxes[var]]; 
    InputField[
     Dynamic[boxes, 
      Function[result, boxes = result; var = ToExpression[boxes]]], 
     Boxes, FieldSize -> OptionValue[FieldSize]]]
```

And testing:

```
DynamicModule[{b, numFields, fieldvalue}, numFields = 3;
 fieldvalue[index_] = 0;
 b[index_] = Null;
 Column[{Row[{"Number of fields: ", 
     SetterBar[Dynamic[numFields], Range[5]]}], 
   Panel[Dynamic[
     Column[Row[{"Field ", #, ": ", 
          HoldInputField[fieldvalue[#], b[#]], " = ", 
          fieldvalue[#]}] & /@ Range[numFields]]]]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ClearAll[numfields, fieldvalue]

DynamicModule[{numfields = 3}, 
  Column[{Row[{"Number of fields: ", SetterBar[Dynamic[numFields], Range[5]]}], 
   Dynamic @ Panel[Column[Row[{"Field ", #, ": ", 
          InputField[Dynamic@fieldvalue[#], Boxes], " = ", 
          Dynamic@ToExpression@fieldvalue[#]}] & /@ Range[numFields]]]}], 
   Initialization -> {fieldvalue[_] = 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. So basically this is an example of leaving the input as boxes, and only interpreting it as a number when needed. Given how many places I use the numbers, that is slightly less than ideal (it will expand already-large code and cause lots of re-evaluations of ToExpression that aren't needed). But I definitely grant you that this works. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin, thank you for the vote.